# A 500 error logged in iis logs for a classic asp application

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have traditionally worked with ASP.Net and webforms and I'm not familiar with VBScript and Classic ASP. Unfortunately my new job requires me to work on Classic ASP and VBScript. I need some help in diagnosing this bug where the error

> |42|800a01c2|Wrong_number_of_arguments_or_invalid_property_assignment:_'SESSION'

is being logged for the URI Query (cs-uri-query) section in the IIS logs.

I've been trying to figure it out for the last 2 days but I've had no luck.
All my googling has not got me any good answer (or maybe I wasn't looking in the right area). The Wrong_number_of_arguments_or_invalid_property_assignment says that wrong params or wrong number of params is being passed in to some method. But the _SESSION is perplexing.

Here is the full error log line.

```
2019-05-31 19:46:39 server-ip GET stem-uri |42|800a01c2|Wrong_number_of_arguments_or_invalid_property_assignment:_'SESSION' 443 - client-ip user-agent referrer-link 500 0 0 93
```

I don't have any code to show here unfortunately. This is a legacy application and I don't have any idea where this could be throwing up from. The configuration for this ASP site is bewildering.

Comment: without any code? i don't think so

Answer (score 2):

So I realized this error was being thrown because the entire session variable was being nullified by this statement in one of the files. SESSION = "".
Once this was changed to SESSION.Abandon, the error went away.

Basically, IIS did not like the session variable being nullified that way.